# How to target direct child from element

Tags: javascript

How can I get direct child from element section?

I've tried target it by query selector, but it didn't work. For this case I don't want to use class or id.

Am I using it correctly?

I want to target it from section.

Thanks for help.

```
var section = document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0];
var div = section.querySelector(section + "> div"); //this not work

<section>
  <form>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </form>
  <div> //I want target this div
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: childNodes[0] should do

Comment: `section + "> div"` = `"[object HTMLDivElement]> div"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating `section.querySelector(section + "> div")` a string with and object which is not work in `querySelector`
 BTW if you use `section.querySelector("div")` it will return the first `div` of the elements so what you want is `section.querySelectorAll("div")[2]` which point to third `div` see the example in two parts, the second one is yours.

```js
var section = document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0];
var div = section.querySelector("div"); //this not work 
console.log(div);

//What you want
var section = document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0];
var div = section.querySelectorAll("div"); //this not work
var target = div[2];
console.log(target);
```

```html
<section>
  <form>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </form>
  <div> I want target this div
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

in the other side you can set an `id` for that div and directly find it by `getElementById` but from you mentioned you don't want find it by `class` or `id`.

**UPDATE:**
At least there should be an info about your target `div` to be able find it either added dynamically or statically, if you can not define `class` or `id` it is good to define and attribute like `<dive attName='value'></div>` or you can find it by content.
Therefore there should be a specific position for your target `div` it is not possible to find a div when you don't have any information about it. if that div have specific content you can iterate all div in a for and check it, but the best way is defining `class` or `id` for that div or at least defining an attribute for it.

Comment: Ty, and do you know how to do it if in form are divs created dynamically? or if there are many of them?

Comment: Therefore there should be a specific position for your target `div` it is not possible to find a div when you don't have any information about it. if that dive have specific content you can iterate all div in a `for` and check it, but the best way is defining `class` or  `id` for that `div` or at least defining an attribute for it.

Comment: You are welcome, if it gives you the clue and resolved your problem please check it as answer.

Comment: @Martin54 Your subject -> `How to target direct child from element`, this answer does not do that,. What problem do you have with quirimmo answer?

Comment: @Keith, He mentioned he don't want find it by `id` in content of question but you are right subject says directly, but I mentioned there is no way better than defining `id` or `class`

Comment: quirimmo's answer doesn't find by using an `id`..  It's using a direct child selector, ` > `

Comment: but `section > div` don't find third `div` directly, should find it by index.

Comment: Did you try running his snippet?, it certainly finds the correct `div`, that's why he put the `id` on there, it was to confirm it was finding the correct div, because when  running the snippet it would be difficult to see it's the correct div otherwise.  IOW; the `id` wasn't required to make it work, just to show it working.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use query selector specifying the selector like `section > div` directly:

```js
var div = document.querySelector("section > div"); 
console.log(div);
```

```html
<section>
  <form>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </form>
  <div id="my-target-element"> //I want target this div
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If you really want to do that on the `section` element, get the element and then use the query selector like below, looking directly for the child `div` element:

```js
const section = document.querySelector('section');
console.log(section.querySelector('section > div'));
// or even
console.log(section.querySelectorAll('div')[2]);
```

```html
<section>
  <form>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </form>
  <div id="my-target-element"> //I want target this div
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: ty, but I want it target it from the section, not from document

Comment: but it target first div in form element

Comment: @Martin54  You could just retarget from itself,.. eg.  `section.parentElement.querySelector('section>div')`  This will still select only the DIV that's a direct child of section then, rather than having to know it's the 3rd div if using querySelectorAll.

Comment: it is returning the first `div` as you can set content for `div`s and see the output.

Comment: @Keith I just edited again showing even the id of the retrieved element.

Comment: he don't want use `id` or `class`

Comment: @Aria id is to show that when you console log the element, that's the right one to be picked up

Answer (score 0):

var div = section.querySelector("section > div");

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely too late, but any way…
there is a pseudo-class, [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope), for this purpose.
It targets the root element of `querySelector`, so the solution would be:

```js
var div = section.querySelector(":scope>div");
```